# greater, higher, or more

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm wondering which word to use in the following:

> The numbeer (referring to 2,500,000 kilos of food) is 24% greater / higher / more than that in 2010.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your options are idiomatic and understandable. As a matter of style, “greater” seems preferable when discussing numbers.